# Suggestions re where to drop a pointer to the industry's description of credit scores?

Tags: discussion

If this were a real FAQ system, I'd drop a clip from or a pointer to 
http://www.myfico.com/CreditEducation/WhatsInYourScore.aspx into the credit-score topic. Not sure now best to do that here.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do it is probably to post it (along with a summary) as an answer to this question:

[What is the full formula for calculating a FICO 9 credit score?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/46548/10997)

The biggest problem with this FICO page, in my opinion, is that it generates more questions than it does answers.  It gives these vague categories and assigns percentages to them, but has no specifics on what you actually need to do to raise your score.

---

**(Rambling aside.  Don't bother reading.)**

I do like FICO's [Improve Your Score](http://www.myfico.com/CreditEducation/ImproveYourScore.aspx) page, which does offer some genuinely helpful advice that goes against what so many people think is the right way to game the credit score.  I was surprised to see that FICO says this on that page:

> Don't open a number of new credit cards that you don't need, just to increase your available credit.
>   This approach could backfire and actually lower your credit scores.

and

> Reduce the Amount of Debt You Owe – This is easier said than done, but reducing the amount that you owe is going to be a far more satisfying achievement than improving your credit score. The first thing you need to do is stop using your credit cards. Use your credit report to make a list of all of your accounts and then go online or check recent statements to determine how much you owe on each account and what interest rate they are charging you. Come up with a payment plan that puts most of your available budget for debt payments towards the highest interest cards first, while maintaining minimum payments on your other accounts.

It's nice to see those on FICO's site, especially since we get so many questions and answers on this site from people that think they need to drag out their loans as long as possible and sign up for a bunch of extra credit cards to be successful.

If you want to be amazed, read a few threads on FICO's [message boards](http://ficoforums.myfico.com/), especially the [Credit Card Approvals section](http://ficoforums.myfico.com/t5/Credit-Card-Approvals/bd-p/App_Approvals).  You wouldn't believe how excited some people get about applying for credit cards.  They proudly show off how many cards they have, what their credit limit is, and their credit scores.  One user has 29 credit cards for a total of over $700k limit.  Even with all that, his score is not all that high (740).  Interesting.  I suppose it is no different than any other game people play, trying to get a high score.  But I don't know what purpose it serves to have that much available credit.

Comment: Mostly what you need to do to raise your score is follow the 0th Commandment: Don't Be Stupid. But people don't like that answer; they want    to be able to blame a rigged system.

Comment: "0th Commandment: Don't Be Stupid." That would make a great bumper sticker.